# switching component for ghc-mod

Tags: haskell, ghc-mod

I have a project whose main cabal component is a library

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  ...
```

and which also defines

```
executable todo
   if !flag(example)
        Buildable: False
   ghc-options: -Wall
   cpp-options: -DGHCJS_BROWSER

   default-language: Haskell2010
   hs-source-dirs: example/todo
   other-modules: TodoDispatcher
                  TodoStore
                  TodoComponents


   main-is: Main.hs
```

Now if I try to type check one file I get the following error

```
Configuring react-flux-1.0.3...
EXCEPTION: types:
           Could not find module ‘TodoDispatcher’
           Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

And if I do so from the command line I get

```
 $ ghc-mod  --ghcOpt=-v7 type example/todo/TodoViews.hs 29 28                                            not sandboxed
EXCEPTION: types:
           Could not find module ‘TodoDispatcher’
           Locations searched:
             .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.8.0/build/TodoDispatcher.hs
             .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.8.0/build/TodoDispatcher.lhs
             .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.8.0/build/TodoDispatcher.hsig
             .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.8.0/build/TodoDispatcher.lhsig
             src/TodoDispatcher.hs
             src/TodoDispatcher.lhs
             src/TodoDispatcher.hsig
             src/TodoDispatcher.lhsig
             .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.8.0/build/autogen/TodoDispatcher.hs
             .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.8.0/build/autogen/TodoDispatcher.lhs
             .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.8.0/build/autogen/TodoDispatcher.hsig
             .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.8.0/build/autogen/TodoDispatcher.lhsig
```

So it seems to ignore the `hs-source-dirs` setting of the component which the current file I try to typecheck belongs to, and instead consider the one from the first component of the package, just like [cabal repl](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html) would do  by default

`By default cabal repl loads the first component in a package.`

How can I change that nice bit of global state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so here's what you should do in order to get this to work:

- You need to edit the cabal file and change the flag of the component to

  ```
  `Buildable : True`
  ```
- You can then type check

  ```
   $ ghc-mod --ghcOpt=-v7 type example/todo/TodoViews.hs 29 28                                            not sandboxed
   29 24 29 34 "[Char]"
   27 25 33 12 "TextInputArgs"
   27 9 33 12 "ReactElementM [
  ```

In Emacs:

- You need to get out of Emacs maybe
- You need to open your file and `haskell-process-load-file` (aka C-c C-l, aka Space m s b)

It should have loaded the correct "target", which is haskell-mode parlance for "component" in cabal. If that works then ghc-mod should also. (?)

http://haskell.github.io/haskell-mode/manual/latest/Interactive-Haskell.html

> #### 14.8.1 Changing REPL target
>
> With haskell-session-change-target you can change the target for REPL session.
>
> After REPL session started, in haskell-interactive-mode buffer invoke the haskell-session-change-target and select from available targets for
>
> - Testing
> - Benchmark
> - Executable
> - Library
>
> Answer “yes” to restart the session and run your tests, benchmarks, executables.